# "minAccessRole" on Google Calendar API, what is the order?

Tags: permissions, google-api, google-calendar-api

According to Google Calendar API v3 you can set a `minAccessRole`;

> The minimum access role for the user in the returned entries. Optional.
>   The default is no restriction.

There are 4 values;

- "freeBusyReader": The user can read free/busy information.
- "owner": The user can read and modify events and access control lists.
- "reader": The user can read events that are not private.
- "writer": The user can read and modify events.

What i'm trying to work out is, what is the order? What calendars should I be seeing if I set a `minAccessRole`?

It seems fairly obvious, but the order order they write them is throwing me off as it seems the `reader` role is sandwiched between `writer` and `owner` which doesn't seem correct to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i will have to agree that the order is misleading.  The following order is probably more sensible.   The information found on the [Sharing and Attendees](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/sharing#sharing_calendars) page is probably more actuate.

> The owners of a calendar can share the calendar by giving access to other users. The sharing settings of a given calendar are represented by the ACL collection (access control list) of that calendar. Each resource in the ACL collection grants a specified grantee a certain access role, which is one of those listed in the following table:

- **none** Provides no access.
- **freeBusyReader**   Lets the grantee see whether the calendar is free or busy at a given time, but does not allow access to event details. Free/busy information can be retrieved using the freeBusy.query operation.
- **reader**   Lets the grantee read events on the calendar.
- **writer**   Lets the grantee read and write events on the calendar.
- **owner**    Provides ownership of the calendar. This role has all of the permissions of the writer role with the additional ability to see and manipulate ACLs.